# Nested loops: implementing a loop within a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

So I have to use the following arrays to make a daily planner for the week:

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

activities = ["grump", "teach", "hype", "sleep"];
```

For each thing, I want to the know the number of the day and want the output in the console to look like this: (Monday's activities start at 1)

```
=> Monday
=> grump1
=> teach1
=> hype1
=> sleep1
=> Tuesday
=> grump2
=> teach2
=> hype2
=> sleep2
=> Wednesday
```

etc.

So I'm assuming I have to implement a loop within a loop but I am clueless as to how to approach this. Do I start out with a for loop? Please help.

Comment: Did you try a `for` loop inside another `for` loop?  What did you try?

Comment: Did you try to solve even *part* of the problem?

Comment: Well, you seem to know that you have to iterate over the arrays. So yeah, start with a `for` loop. How else would you iterate over the array?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is forEach:

```
days.forEach(function(day, i) { //forEach day in days
    console.log(day);
    activities.forEach(function(thing) {
        console.log(thing + (i + 1)); //+ 1 because array indicies start 0
    });
});
```

Comment: forEach has been around since IE8, so it is usually safe to use today. Unless you're doing client work and need to go back further than IE 8

Comment: @amenthes unless you have a lot of clients in China, its unlikely to be an issue, and its trivial to polyfill in any case.

Comment: as i said, it is usually safe to use today ;-)